# composer on system with differents php installation Cpanel

Tags: php, composer-php, cpanel, shebang

I need use composer for a project on any servers.

This server has a very old PHP version on system.

But i don't need to use Cpanel PHP version.

I need for my own program use Cpanel internal version locate at /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/php/54/

I try modify shebang

Original

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

Changed

```
#!/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/php/54/
```

But not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/php/54/` includes a php binary you have to give that path to shebang:

```
#!/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/php/54/php
```

Also you should be able to call `/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/php/54/php composer.phar`.

Comment: A lot of thanks. Work for calling with <path to php binary> </path/composer> <option composer>

Comment: A lot of thanks. Work for calling with <path to php binary> </path/composer> <option composer>